# Trouble mounting an sd card

Tags: mount

While attempting to mount and sdcard from `/dev/sda/`

```
mount /dev/sda /media
```

I get an error

```
VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the sd card is at sda? That would usually only be the case if you have no other hard disk drives...

Comment: what system are you on? Normally with unity ubuntu should mount the sdcard automatically. The error messages on the other hand gives a hint of what to do: You have to specify the file system - this should be vfat.

Comment: additionally, you generally wouldn't mount anything on /media directly - it would generally be something like /media/sdcard instead. But ubuntu should automatically set that up as Thomas said.

Comment: I've answered, but if this is not a Ubuntu problem, it may be more appropriate on U&L.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use fdisk to check the disk type

```
fdisk -l
```

Use the information from there as the fs type parameter to mount,

```
mount -t FSTYPE /dev/sdX DIR
```

where FSTYPE is the file system type reported by fdisk, and DIR is the mount point, ie where you want to mount the sd card too.

Additional options to `mount` can be checked using

```
man mount
```

or from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

As an alternative to mount you might also consider `pmount` which can be used by non-root users. The call to `pmount` is also simpler.

See [here for further information](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pmount.1.html) on that.

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

mean you must supply filesystem type, if not default (ext4)

```
mount -t filesystem /dev/sda1 /media
```

Where filesystem

```
ext3 for ext3
vfat for FAT32
ntfs-3g for NTFS
```

use [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html) for complete options

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to use

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

instead, as that would mount the first partition. Furthermore, I doubt that your SD card is really `/dev/sda`.

To identify your SD card, run `fdisk -l` before inserting it. Run it afterwards and your SD card is the new disk. Notice that it will have 1 or more partitions, which will have names of the form `/dev/sdxy`, where `x` is a letter and `y` a number.